# How to get the value from rendering parameters from VariantListsRenderingModel?

Tags: sxa, rendering-parameters

How to get the value from this type of model in the code. I have a simple carousel and I can get values easily from fields now I just want to get the `Rendering Parameters` for this specific rendering. Is that possible to do if the model is `VariantListsRenderingModel`?

This is what I mean by this:`

[image]

Comment: Did you try getting these rendering parameters with traditional approach? Like - https://www.logicalfeed.com/posts/114/rendering-parameters-in-sitecore-with-example

Comment: I did not tried this but hopefully it will work. I did not tried it beacuse it is SXA Model so do not know if it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the rendering parameters value in the view as well as in the controller.

Try to use the below code in the view

```
@{
    string name=""
    var renderingContext = Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingContext.CurrentOrNull;
    if (renderingContext != null)
    {
        var parms = renderingContext.Rendering.Parameters;
        name= parms["name of the field here"];
    }
}
```

In  the controller, you can use the below code :

```
 var addtionalCssParameter = RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Parameters["name of the field"];
```

Both approach will work in SXA. If you will get an issue in SXA then you can try this code in the view.

```
@{
    string name= Convert.ToString(Model.Rendering.Parameters["name of the field"]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! @Ashish